# Pine script: ist it possible to evaluate next candle values? to get relative lowest

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

- I'm trying to detect the if each candle is the lowest value, checking 5 previous candles lows and 5 next candles lows
- I found no problem with previous:

  `if ta.lowest(low, 5) == low 
      line.new(bar_index - 1, low, bar_index + 1, low, color = color.red, width = 1)`

To evaluate if current canle is lower than next ones, I've tried to use negative value on "ta.lowest(low, -5)" but it does not work.
Can you give me a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to detect the if each candle is the lowest value, checking
> 5 previous candles lows and 5 next candles lows

What you have described is implemented in the built-in ta.pivotlow() function, it searches for a pattern and finds the lowest value in the given range to the left (leftbars= argument) and to the right (rightbars=).

As was mentioned, you can't look into the future bars, so the result of the pivot function lags to the amount of bars declared with the rightbars= argument. Note that the plotshape() function uses the same offset as the rightbars= argument.

```
//@version=5
indicator("pivotlow", overlay = true)
leftbars = 5
rightbars = 5
pivLow = ta.pivotlow(leftbars, rightbars)
plotshape(pivLow, style = shape.labelup, location = location.belowbar, offset = - rightbars)
```

[image]

Comment: Aw yeah. Understand. Thank you! This will make me easier to find isolated mins and maxs.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in PineScript to “look into the future”. PineScript is designed to make trading strategies and it would become a bit broken, if it was possible to look into the future. That is why you can’t look at the “next candle”.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcus. Also, it is possible to declare a global variable and assign/evaluate it for each candle?

Comment: @juanan If you type "var" before the variable, then it becomes global and you can assign a value and access it on the next bar.